# Set content of infowindow as html of another component

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to set content of infowindow as html from another componenent?

I am using google map api v3 and angular2.

I have the following string to set as content in the infowindow.

```
var Content='<div style="width :250px; height :210px;"><h3>';
                Content+=detail.name;
                Content+='</h3><br><h5><strong>Website : </strong>';
                Content+=detail.website;
                Content+='</h5><br><h5><strong>Phone : </strong>';
                Content+=detail.phone;
                Content+='</h5></div>';

               infowindow.setContent(Content);
```

I want to move all this html 'Content' and the variable used in it to another component and then set the content of the infowindow using that component.

I am able to make a separate component and generate the required html with the variables but I am not able to use that to set as content in the infowindow.

Comment: Ofc it is. Infowindow is just a html div element. Set whatever content you want into it

Comment: @abeyaz Will you please give an example? I am unable to do so using the method infowindow.setContent() method.

Comment: I cannot know what exactly you want to do wthout any example. Please share a fiddle or some code, so i can help

Comment: Here, the important question is what is your component ? How do you add that to the page ? Basically, you can insert a div to infowindow with an `id` and then add your component into that div. But i dont use angular so i cant help much if you mean angular components.

Comment: @abeyaz Okay thanks

Comment: Did you make it work?